# Echo a Joomla component variable in a module position

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-component

I have a custom Joomla portfolio component that outputs the following code (below). What i want to be able to do is to echo the name variable in a module on the same page but my current attempts have not worked. Is this possible and if so where am I going wrong?

My component default.php output...

```
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

 //Load admin language file
 $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
 $lang->load('com_portfolio', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR);

?>
<?php if ($this->item) : ?>

<div class="item_fields">

    <ul class="fields_list">

                    <li><?php echo JText::_('COM_PORTFOLIO_FORM_LBL_TEMPLATE_ID'); ?>:
        <?php echo $this->item->id; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo JText::_('COM_PORTFOLIO_FORM_LBL_TEMPLATE_ORDERING'); ?>:
        <?php echo $this->item->ordering; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo JText::_('COM_PORTFOLIO_FORM_LBL_TEMPLATE_STATE'); ?>:
        <?php echo $this->item->state; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo JText::_('COM_PORTFOLIO_FORM_LBL_TEMPLATE_CHECKED_OUT'); ?>:
        <?php echo $this->item->checked_out; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo JText::_('COM_PORTFOLIO_FORM_LBL_TEMPLATE_CHECKED_OUT_TIME'); ?>:
        <?php echo $this->item->checked_out_time; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo JText::_('COM_PORTFOLIO_FORM_LBL_TEMPLATE_CREATED_BY'); ?>:
        <?php echo $this->item->created_by; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo JText::_('COM_PORTFOLIO_FORM_LBL_TEMPLATE_NAME'); ?>:
        <?php echo $this->item->name; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo JText::_('COM_PORTFOLIO_FORM_LBL_TEMPLATE_CUSTOM_CLASS'); ?>:
        <?php echo $this->item->custom_class; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo JText::_('COM_PORTFOLIO_FORM_LBL_TEMPLATE_CATEGORY'); ?>:
        <?php echo $this->item->category_title; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo JText::_('COM_PORTFOLIO_FORM_LBL_TEMPLATE_THUMB'); ?>:
        <?php echo $this->item->thumb; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo JText::_('COM_PORTFOLIO_FORM_LBL_TEMPLATE_IMAGE1'); ?>:
        <?php echo $this->item->image1; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo JText::_('COM_PORTFOLIO_FORM_LBL_TEMPLATE_IMAGE2'); ?>:
        <?php echo $this->item->image2; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo JText::_('COM_PORTFOLIO_FORM_LBL_TEMPLATE_IMAGE3'); ?>:
        <?php echo $this->item->image3; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo JText::_('COM_PORTFOLIO_FORM_LBL_TEMPLATE_IMAGE4'); ?>:
        <?php echo $this->item->image4; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo JText::_('COM_PORTFOLIO_FORM_LBL_TEMPLATE_DESCRIPTION'); ?>:
        <?php echo $this->item->description; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo JText::_('COM_PORTFOLIO_FORM_LBL_TEMPLATE_STATS'); ?>:
        <?php echo $this->item->stats; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo JText::_('COM_PORTFOLIO_FORM_LBL_TEMPLATE_DEMO_LINK'); ?>:
        <?php echo $this->item->demo_link; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo JText::_('COM_PORTFOLIO_FORM_LBL_TEMPLATE_BUY_LINK'); ?>:
        <?php echo $this->item->buy_link; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo JText::_('COM_PORTFOLIO_FORM_LBL_TEMPLATE_TAGS'); ?>:
        <?php echo $this->item->tags; ?></li>


    </ul>

</div>
```

And what I would like to do is to echo out the name variable into a module - here's what I tried...

```
<?php 
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Access Deny');
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$lang->load('com_portfolio');
?>


<?php echo JText::_('COM_PORTFOLIO_FORM_LBL_TEMPLATE_NAME'); ?>:
<?php echo $item->name; ?>
```

The component functions fine and the module does too with a simple hello world echo so I am out of ideas.

Comment: I know remember why I stopped messing around with Joomla!

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple workaround. I simply set a session

```
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$session->set( 'myVar', $this->item->name );
```

and the echoed it in my module...

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($session->get( 'myVar', 'empty' )); ?>
```

I dont know if this is an altogether safe or efficient way to work but it at least functions for now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the model from the component in the module. Something like the following code can get the item in the module

```
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_portfolio/models', 'PortfolioModel');
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Portfolio', 'PortfolioModel');
$model->getState();
// if you want to set a state
$model->setState('filter.category_id', $catid);
$item = $model->getItem();
```

In the model itself you can then cache the item to prevent a second database access. An other way to solve it.